# How do I fix "The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object"?

Tags: discord

So I made a bot which plays music and also some other commands and I am trying to play audio with a URL but in return is

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "file" argument must be of type string. Received type object
```

```
  function play(guild, song) {
    const serverQueue = queue.get(guild.id);
    if (!song) {
      serverQueue.voiceChannel.leave();
      queue.delete(guild.id);
      return;
    }

    const dispatcher = serverQueue.connection
      .play(ytdl(song.url))
      .on("finish", () => {
        serverQueue.songs.shift();
        play(guild, serverQueue.songs[0]);
      })
      .on("error", error => console.error(error));
    dispatcher.setVolumeLogarithmic(serverQueue.volume / 5);
    serverQueue.textChannel.send(`Start playing: **${song.title}**`);
  }
  client.login(token);
```

The part is what I think causes the error because it says in the output the line which is mainly the line where play is, I am not really experienced in this so if anyone can provide help then it will be appreciated.